# Data Factory how to get heavily nested JSON from API into SQL database

Tags: sql, azure-data-factory

I have an API that is returning some JSON in the following format:

```
{"meta":
    {"pagination":
        {
        "pageSize":10,
        "totalCount":16,
        "next":"eNoljrsOgjAAAP-lqyTy8AEm_8-fL-kXQCg"
        },
        "status":200
        },
    "data":[
        {"items":[
            {"name":"Anne A",
            "email":"anne.A@companyA.nz",
            "templateName":"Document shared with you",
            "department":"DS",
            "status":"SENT",
            "numCampaignsSent":16,
            "numCampaignsClicked":2,
            "numTrainingModulesAssigned":13,
            "numCorrectAnswers":0,"
            numIncorrectAnswers":0,
            "userState":"ACTIVE",
            "clickedIp":""
            },
            {"name":"Barbara B",
            "email":"barbara.B@companyA.nz",
            "templateName":"Document shared with you",
            "department":"DS",
            "status":"OPENED",
            "timeOpened":"2022-04-25T20:29:48+0000",
            "numCampaignsSent":17,
            "numCampaignsClicked":1,
            "numTrainingModulesAssigned":11,
            "numCorrectAnswers":3,
            "numIncorrectAnswers":2,
            "userState":"ACTIVE",
            "clickedIp":""
            }
```

Normally we ingest the data into a single cell in a SQL table and then run a stored proc to move the data to a stage.delta table.  This runs really well for all of our API's so far.  We normally use a Web Task for this.

I have tried using a copy task for this instance, but believe that this doesnt work because the data array is too deep for the copy task to interpret.  I had opted to use the copy task because it offers pagination, which the web task doesnt do.

However, as I will be passing the "next" {id} inside the body of the API call, I am not sure that this is such an issue.

I have now managed to get the data exported using a copy task to blob storage to then process, as this seems to be the next best option.  However, I am struggling with the concept of how I am going to extract the "next" details to process back into the pipeline so that another API call can be made.

So, I could extract the JSON for page 1 and paste it in a single cell in a table and then process from there, but cant work out how to get the pagination to work.  OR I could paste it to a blob storage, and then process from there, but cant work out how to feed the pagination value back in so that the process can repeat.

Can anyone help or provide an example of having faced this challenge before?

Here is my body call so far:

```
`{
"meta": {"pagination":{"pageToken":"addtokenhere"}},
"data": [{"id":"{itemIDgoeshere}"}]}`
```

I have tried a copy task - straight API to table but fails on the JSON as it is too many layers deep to process.  I have also tried to get the JSON into blob storage and process from there, but am struggling with how to process the pagination when the API call has already happened.